# Google Charts: Autoscale the Vertical Axis

Tags: google-sheets, charts

In a chart where I select a Stock and display it (utilising GoogleFinance) for a selected time period, the Vertical Axis always starts at **zero**.   In the case of Apple, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to "autoscale" (?) the Y axis so that it displays values that are more appropriate, eg from ~$100 to ~$180 or something similar?

I know that I can **manually** set the Minimum and Maximum values for the Y axis, just wondering if there is something "built-in" that can automatically do this?

Comment: Do you mean logarithmic (log) scale?

Comment: No.  In the above example, I'd like the Minimum Value of the Vertical Scale to be something like: =MIN(myValueRange)*0.9.

Comment: I do not think range reference is supported in the axis scale, so the answer in 'no'.

Comment: No, doesn't look like it.  I'm now searching for a way to change the Minimum Value using script, then add the function to a button.

Comment: You are asking for "built-in". So I told you no.